# static enum ignore warning inside the class

Tags: c++

I have a Class and this code inside:

```
public:
    static enum AnimalTypes {Mammals, Fish, Birds, Horse, MammalsFish, Flamingo, GoldFish, Mermaid};
```

but then i get this warning :

```
Warning C4091 'static ': `ignored on left of 'const Zoo::AnimalTypes' when no variable is declared   Line 269`
```

what cause this problem?

Comment: `static const` should not be here.

Comment: What is supposed to be `static` or `const`?

Comment: i removed the const and its still showing the same warning :(

Comment: You've removed the `const` (keeping the `static`), same warning.  You've removed the `static` (keeping the `const`), same warning.  What happens if you remove both the `static` and the `const`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from your comments you are trying to declare a enumeration type `AnimalTypes` which can be used all the classes in your code.

For a globel enmu use as follows in a header file.

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

enum AnimalTypes {Mammals, Fish, Birds, Horse, MammalsFish, Flamingo, GoldFish, Mermaid};
```

this can be access from any of your class,

```
AnimalTypes  at = Mammals;
```

But if you declare your enum inside the class, accessing style is bit different.

```
class Base
{
public:

enum AnimalTypes {Mammals, Fish, Birds, Horse, MammalsFish, Flamingo, GoldFish, Mermaid};
  ...
};
```

access style,

```
Base::AnimalTypes bat = Base::Mammals;
```

You should not use `static` to declare a enumeration type. But you can use it to declare class variable.

Answer (score 1):

**static** - mean a class variable, rather than an instance variable.
**const** - mean a none mutable (a non-changeable) variable.
both not relevant for enum definition. enum is not a variable.

so it should be:

```
public:
    enum AnimalTypes {Mammals, Fish, Birds, Horse, MammalsFish, Flamingo, GoldFish, Mermaid};
```

Comment: But i don't want every class to have the same animal type. i want a global animal type for all the class

Comment: @OpalKoren What makes you think, that every class will have the same animal type? `AnimalTypes` is **not** a variable. It's a type.

Comment: so enum works like static, its creates only one to all class?

Comment: @OpalKoren Please elaborate on what you mean by "_so enum works like static, its creates only one to all class?_" Enum is a type (like a `class`), that can only contain a value from a predefined list of values (specified in `enum` definition). To actually store said value, you need to have a variable. As answer (and your compiler) stated: Both `static`, and `const` are applicable only to variables, and not types, hence why your compiler ignored such statements, and issued a warning for them.

Comment: @OpalKoren `enum` declaration does not create any variables. `Mammals` `Fish` and other values are not stored anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You've got `static const` there which suggests that you're trying to declare a class member variable, but then you've also got `enum AnimalTypes {...}` which suggests you're trying to declare an enumeration type.

If you're trying to do the first thing (you're probably not), then put the variable name between the closing brace and the semicolon. If you're trying to declare an enumeration type, you should not have `static const`. Those keywords apply to variables, not to type declarations.

Comment: i removed the const and its still showing the same warning :(